# Градиент svg css, проблема firefox

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, firefox

Заливается svg градиентом прекрасно в chrome,в firefox не работает, пишет не найдено

```
fill: url(#GradientStatsOrange);
```

Код градиента:

```
<symbol id="Gradient_raiting_main_v3" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; preserveAspectRatio="none"> 
 <style type="text/css"> 
 rect{fill:url(#GradientBellBlue)}
 </style> 
 <defs> <linearGradient id="GradientBellBlue"> <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#53c2bf" /> <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4ea2d3" /> </linearGradient> </defs>
 <rect width="100" height="50"/> 
 </symbol>
```

Comment: Укажи абсолютный путь до свг, скажем fill: url('/assets/svg/gradient.svg#GradientStatsOrange')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Вы не привели код градиента, поэтому</strike> подключаю свой градиент для оформления текста.

**CSS**

```
#txt1 {
fill:url(#Gradient-1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<text id="txt1" x="15%" y="75%" font-size= "200px" font-weight= "bold"
  font-family= " 'Signika', sans-serif"  >Apple</text>
```

Ниже работающий во всех браузерах и даже в IE11 пример:

```css
#txt1 {
fill:url(#Gradient-1);
}
```

```html
<svg  width="750" height="300" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 750 300"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                   
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient-1" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text id="txt1" x="15%" y="75%" font-size= "200px" font-weight= "bold"
  font-family= " 'Signika', sans-serif"  >Stack</text>
  </svg>
```

### UPD

Добавлен пример от автора вопроса.

Вы немного запутались в тегах, заменил `<symbol>` на `<svg>` и всё заработало

```html
<svg id="Gradient_raiting_main_v3" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; preserveAspectRatio="none"> 
 <style type="text/css"> 
 rect{
 fill:url(#GradientBellBlue)
 }
 </style> 
 <defs> <linearGradient id="GradientBellBlue"> <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#53c2bf" /> <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4ea2d3" /> </linearGradient> 
 </defs>
 <rect width="100" height="50"/> 
 </svg>
```

Comment: Минусующий и вопрос и ответ, что не так?

Comment: Тут просто с недавнего времени завелось несколько кадров, которые считают, что нужно обязательно минусовать все ответы на вопросы, которые для них слишком просты или ответ на которые можно найти где-то еще.

Comment: <symbol id="Gradient_raiting_main_v3" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<style type="text/css">
        rect{fill:url(#GradientBellBlue)}
      </style>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="GradientBellBlue">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#53c2bf" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4ea2d3" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      
      <rect width="100" height="50"/>

</symbol> это код градиента

Comment: Вообщем ссылка на symbol внутри svg не работает, только на ссылку отдельную svg

Comment: @ЭльдарГучеренко добавил ваш код градиента из комментария в сам вопрос. Сейчас попробую рассмотреть в чём проблема. Сразу могу сказать, что код находящийся в тегах `symbol` и `defs` не виден по умолчанию и его надо вызывать командой use.

Comment: @Cheg если замечаете серийное минусование, то напишите админам. Если ваши догадки подтвердятся - минусы откатят.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете , то он по умолчанию лежит внутри svg defs.
Соответственно, вложенный внутрь символа defs Firefox не понимает. Сделайте так:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="GradientBellBlue"> <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#53c2bf" /><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4ea2d3" /></linearGradient>
    <symbol id="Gradient_raiting_main_v3" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; preserveAspectRatio="none"> 
      <rect width="100" height="50" fill="url(#GradientBellBlue)"/> 
    </symbol>
  </defs>
<svg>
```